# After migration from magento 1 to magento 2 customers giving eror

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, magento2-migration-tool

After migrating data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 When I click on customers in admin area it gives this error

[image]

> {"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: 
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config","1":"#1
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called
>   at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#2
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]\n#3
>   Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:642]\n#4
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php:68]\n#5
>   Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php:87]\n#6
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php:119]\n#7
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CachedMetadata.php:85]\n#8
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CachedMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/AttributeRepository.php:83]\n#9
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository->getList()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php:102]\n#10
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns->prepare() called
>   at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#11
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->___callParent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#12
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [app/code/Amasty/Orderattr/Model/ResourceModel/Value/Plugin/Order/Grid/Columns.php:58]\n#13
>   Amasty\Orderattr\Model\ResourceModel\Value\Plugin\Order\Grid\Columns->aroundPrepare()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#14
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#15
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Interceptor.php:26]\n#16
>   Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->prepare()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:164]\n#17
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:161]\n#18
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:142]\n#19
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]\n#20
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]\n#21
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:343]\n#22
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]\n#23
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]\n#24
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]\n#25
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called
>   at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]\n#26
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]\n#27
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]\n#28
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]\n#29
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]\n#30
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:24]\n#31
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php:28]\n#32
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]\n#33
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]\n#34
>   Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#35
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#36
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]\n#37
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#38
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#39
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]\n#40
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#41
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]\n#42
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#43
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#44
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#45
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#46
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]\n#47
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]\n#48
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#49
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at
>   [index.php:39]\n</pre>","url":"/stadmin/customer/index/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: Can you do reindex and set permissions correctly?

Comment: Find the rows that have "frontend_input" is "select" and "source_model" is "NULL" from "eav_attributes" table and check after change from "select" to "text". Please take before change anything in DB.

Comment: I fixed the issue I edited customer_eav_attribute table and removed records, there were some records with wrong Attribute ID table should list in sequence but I found some records where showing like 1,2,3,4,5, 10,12,14,20 I just removed 10,12,14,20 and it worked fine !  if anyone have the same issue I strongly recommend you to take back of table first!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue I edited customer_eav_attribute table and removed records, there were some records with wrong Attribute ID table should list in sequence but I found some records where showing like 1,2,3,4,5, 10,12,14,20 I just removed 10,12,14,20 and it worked fine ! if anyone have the same issue I strongly recommend you to take back of table first!

Comment: Saved me hours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. It turned out to be some extra entries in the "eav_customer_attribute" table. Once I removed these entries the page loaded and worked fine.

I also found that this issue caused the customers address to be saved as a new entry on every order.