# Can not open "Admin -> Customers -> All customers" after Magento 1 to 2 data migration

Tags: magento2, migration, customer-attribute, eav-attributes

I have a similar issue like this one [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300051/after-migration-from-magento-1-to-magento-2-customers-giving-eror), after migrating from Magento 1 to 2.
But the report is a little bit different and the provided solution in the thread did not help me at all.

I already tried to reindex everything and I also tried to change the "select" to "text" on all rows with "frontend_input" is "select" and "source_model" is "NULL" from "eav_attributes" table.

Here is my report:

> {"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config","1":"#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Eav\Mode...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Mode...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]\n#3 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('Magento\Eav\Mode...') called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:642]\n#4 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php:98]\n#5 Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute(&Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute#0000000000128c2a00000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php:87]\n#6 Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata('lb_paymentfilter...') called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php:119]\n#7 Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CachedMetadata.php:85]\n#8 Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CachedMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/AttributeRepository.php:83]\n#9 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository->getList() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php:102]\n#10 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns->prepare() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:164]\n#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(&Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns#0000000000128d5a00000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:161]\n#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(&Magento\Ui\Component\Listing#0000000000128d5d00000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:142]\n#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#000000000012894900000000125d3297#, 'customer_listing', array('attributes' => array('group' => '', 'component' => '', 'aclResource' => '', 'visibilityCondit...' => array())), &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor#00000000001288b800000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]\n#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000000128e4600000000125d3297#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#0000000000128e5f00000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]\n#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000000128e4600000000125d3297#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#0000000000128e5f00000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:350]\n#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]\n#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]\n#18 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]\n#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:257]\n#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:882]\n#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]\n#22 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Customer...') called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php:28]\n#23 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]\n#24 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]\n#25 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#26 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#27 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]\n#28 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000000128f8500000000125d3297#, &Closure#0000000000128f8700000000125d3297#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#29 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#30 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]\n#31 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#, &Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000000128f8500000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:98]\n#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#34 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000000128bd900000000125d3297#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]\n#38 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#39 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000000128b2300000000125d3297#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"/admin_2w4nen/customer/index/index/key/9e9275afcd365e4dcca9442e4189649b85ea2f206005449828f04cc494678da3/","script_name":"/index.php","report_id":"edc4eb43a52bb30d0737256d1cd0d92239ee9fdb320865d7f0a6ab6014301c12"}

Answer (score 0):

You first need to access to the table **customer_eav_attribute** then find the **error attribute** and edit **data_model** to **null**.

Please let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is the "error attribute"? What do I have to search for?

Comment: There is just one row with a **data_model** that is not **NULL**. It is attribute_id 28 (postcode) with the **data_model** `Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Data\Postcode`. But setting this to **NULL** as well, does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by disabling or removing a customer registration attribute extension.

When I disabled or removed the extension the values in the extensions table went missing from the database. They linked to the "customer_eav_attribute" table via the "attribute_id" field.

To resolve this I reinstalled the extension and manually re added linked attributes in the extension's database table. After doing this I deleted them in the magento backend which removed them from the "customer_eav_attribute" table and resolved the issue.

This could relate to your issue in that you may need to clean up non linked "attribute_id"s in the "customer_eav_attribute" table.

I'm working in Magento 2.3.5.