# magento 2 Category Not Showing on frontend after migration

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, sub-categories

I dump the database from Magento 2 to Magento 2 and the sub-category is not saved in database **catalog_category_entity_int**  and from the backend, its show category is enabled but in database its entity_id is not stored [image]

after i click on save btn its entity_id gets stored in this db table **catalog_category_entity_int**

Comment: can you check this table if there is data here catalog_product_index_eav

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326470/categories-not-showing-products-in-frontend-after-migration-from-magento-1-7-2-t